# Finding unique pairs in a character vector in R

Tags: r, vector

I have a vector that is a long list of letters, and I want to find out how many pairs of letters there are? For example, if I have `AABBAAACC` there would be 5 pairs.

I have no idea how to do this.

```
x <- "AABBAAACC"
```

I'm a beginner to R so please be kind!

Answer (score 3):

**1) gregexpr**  Try this:

```
> length(gregexpr("(.)(?=\\1)", "AABBAAACC", perl = TRUE)[[1]])
[1] 5
```

**2) rollapply**

```
> library(zoo)
> > sum(rollapply(strsplit("AABBAAACC", "")[[1]], 2, function(x) x[1] == x[2]))
[1] 5
```

**2a)** or slightly more compact:

```
> library(zoo)
> library(gsubfn)
> sum(fn$rollapply(strsplit("AABBAAACC", "")[[1]], 2, ~ x[1] == x[2]))
[1] 5
```

**3) head/tail**

```
> s <- strsplit("AABBAAACC", "")[[1]]
> sum(tail(s, -1) == head(s, -1))
[1] 5
```

*ADDED* more solutions.

Comment: Well my actual vector is defined as y, so would I just put in: length(gregexpr("(.)(?=\\1)", y, perl = TRUE)[[1]])? When I try it, I just get 1: does this mean there is only one pair? Quite surprising considering there are 50k letters in my list..

Comment: y needs to be a character string

Answer (score 1):

@G. Grothendieck's answer is better but I thought of a non regex approach:

```
runs <- rle(unlist(strsplit("AABBAAACC", NULL)))
sum(runs[[1]][runs[[1]] > 1] - 1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Find the longest run length of one character. Subtract one to get the number of pairs here. Keep adding these.